# Decimal to hex function

Tags: python-3.x, hex

how to improve my code?
my code works fine for binary part and octal part, but when it comes to hex part, I got incorrect for some value, if I want to convert 45 into hex, the correct output should be 2D while I always got 213...

```
def hex(number, base):

    if number == 10:
        return 'A'
    elif number  == 11:
        return 'B'
    elif number  == 12:
        return 'C'
    elif number  == 13:
        return 'D'
    elif number  == 14:
        return 'E'
    elif number  == 15:
        return 'F'
    elif number < 10:
        return str(number)           

    else:
        return hex(number//base, base) + str(number%base)
```

Answer (score 0):

`converter(number//base, base) + str(number%base)` will result in `"2" + "13"`, because `str(45 % 13)` is `"13"`. You should convert that part as well.

Comment: so i should change it to converter(number//base, base) + converter(number%base, base) ?

Comment: Yup. It works for octals and binaries because `str` will handle sub-10 digits just fine, but hex needs to get its digits some way.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to write your own functions for conversions between numeral systems to learn something. For "real" code I would recommend to use build in conversion function from Python [hex(x)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#hex).